# Is there a JSON query class/plugin/function?

Tags: jquery, json

Is there a JSON query class or jQuery plugin that I can use to more easily query larger JSON objects to return smaller sub-sets?

Comment: [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) isn't simple enough for you?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: I do not want to query a server for a JSON response, so $.getJSON doesn't really make any sense here...

I want to query JSON using a LINQ or SQL like syntax to create a smaller subset of data... The most recent question like this is over a year old (that I can find) and nothing at that time seemed very mature.

Comment: JSON is a method of storing JavaScript arrays and objects as strings.  There is no such thing as a "JSON Object".  It's a JavaScript object (or a JSON string).

Comment: @Greg-J: There's [LINQ for JavaScript](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using [jsonSelect](http://jsonselect.org), once you learn how to do the queries it can really simplify things

Comment: This is interesting. I'm not sure if it will work for my needs, but interesting nonetheless. Speed is a necessity for this project, so we'll see how it performs. Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 0):

The power of JavaScript is that you can pass 'smaller pieces' of the whole JavaScript object like so:

```
doSomething(response['objectA']['subB']);
```

Against a data structure like so:

```
{ "objectA" : { "subA" : 0, "subB" : 42 } }
```

The function receives the value of 42.